# About this sentence <I got my hair cut. >

Tags: sentence-meaning, verbs

I am so doubtful about the sentence.
Because I think that could mean both.

One is, most people know well, that someone cut my hair.
The other is, I think it is possible in that the verb 'get' does mean just to transform a situation to another, that I cut my hair so that the hair was from a long to a short.

So we ought to write like this 'I cut my hair' to avoid misunderstanding it to the other case.

Answer (score 1):

"I got my hair cut" is the standard and natural way to express that I "got someone to cut my hair".
I wouldn't worry about confusing anyone by that phrasing.

Comment: Does 'I got my hair cut' could imply both meanings 'I cut my hair' and ' Someone cut my hair'? Because 'I got my hair cut' means just 'My hair has been short'. 
However, other than that sentence, 'I cut my hair' only mean as it is. 
Could my thinking be correct?

Answer (score 1):

"I got my hair cut" is standard and implies that someone else cut your hair at your request.

"I cut my own hair" means you cut it yourself.

A third possibility, that is, I think, what you are talking about in your second meaning, is "my hair got cut".  This is the passive voice and doesn't say anything about who did it.  However, since the other two sentences are standard, this construction implies that some other thing happened.  E.g. someone cut your hair while you slept.  If there was some way that your hair could get shorter by itself, it could mean that, but I can't think of how that could happen.

Comment: Does 'I got my hair cut' could imply both meanings 'I cut my hair' and ' Someone cut my hair'? Because 'I got my hair cut' means just 'My hair has been short'. 
However, other than that sentence, 'I cut my hair' only mean as it is. 
Could my thinking be correct?

Comment: "I got my hair cut" implies that someone else did it.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever I doubt a phrase, I often think it's helpful to see it alongside similar phrases. So

> I got my hair cut at the weekend.

Who cut the hair? Probably the barber or someone, but that doesn't matter and the sentence isn't explicit about who did it.

> His parents withhold his pocket money until he gets his household chores done

Who is eventually going to do those chores? Probably the boy, but there's nothing to say he won't manipulate a younger sibling into doing it.

> After a long struggle with the rusty lock, we finally got that door opened

Who opened the door? I don't know. It might even have swung open by itself once we cut the lock off.

> My computer has been running so slowly lately; I think I need to get it serviced.

Who's going to look at the computer? The sentence doesn't say.

You say you think `the verb 'get' does mean just to transform a situation to another`. I don't agree with that: this construction seems to be about obviating the agency and making more a point of the accomplishment.

Comment: Does 'I got my hair cut' could imply both meanings 'I cut my hair' and ' Someone cut my hair'? Because 'I got my hair cut' means just 'My hair has been short'. 
However, other than that sentence, 'I cut my hair' only mean as it is. 
Could my thinking be correct?

Comment: That's exactly right. This sentence structure is not explicit about who actually does the thing. Could be `I` or someone else.